# Validation Accuracy not improving CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am fairly new to deep learning and right now am trying to predict consumer choices based on EEG data. The total dataset consists of 1045 EEG recordings each with a corresponding label, indicating Like or Dislike for a product. Classes are distributed as follows (44% Likes and 56% Dislikes). I read that Convolutional Neural Networks are suitable to work with raw EEG data so I tried to implement a network based on keras with the following structure:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(full_data, target, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
y_test = np.asarray(y_test).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))


# X_train.shape = ((836, 512, 14))
# y_train.shape = ((836, 1))

from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import MaxPooling1D
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(16, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=(512,14)))

model.add(MaxPooling1D())

model.add(Conv1D(8, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))

model.add(MaxPooling1D())

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=20, batch_size = 64)
```

When I fit the model however the validation accuracy does not change at all with the following output:

```
Epoch 1/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 292.6353 - accuracy: 0.5383 - val_loss: 0.7884 - val_accuracy: 0.5407
Epoch 2/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 1.3748 - accuracy: 0.5598 - val_loss: 0.8860 - val_accuracy: 0.5502
Epoch 3/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 1.0537 - accuracy: 0.5598 - val_loss: 0.7629 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 4/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.8827 - accuracy: 0.5598 - val_loss: 0.7010 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 5/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7988 - accuracy: 0.5598 - val_loss: 0.8689 - val_accuracy: 0.5407
Epoch 6/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 1.0221 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6961 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 7/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7415 - accuracy: 0.5598 - val_loss: 0.6945 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 8/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7381 - accuracy: 0.5574 - val_loss: 0.7761 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 9/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7326 - accuracy: 0.5598 - val_loss: 0.6926 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 10/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7338 - accuracy: 0.5598 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 11/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7203 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6916 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 12/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7192 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6914 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 13/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7174 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6912 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 14/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7155 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6911 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 15/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7143 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6910 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 16/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7129 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6909 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 17/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7114 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6907 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 18/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7103 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6906 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 19/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7088 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6906 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 20/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7075 - accuracy: 0.5610 - val_loss: 0.6905 - val_accuracy: 0.5455
```

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Have you standardized the data before feeding to model? If not try that. Besides, play with convolution layers, and I would recommend to add a fully connected layer before the last layer like "model.add(Dense(128, activation='tanh'))". you can also try to alter the positions of conv layers.

Comment: Yes I standardized the data and like you said added some dense layers, still the same issue

Comment: Is it feasible for you to share the data?

Comment: This is the link to the data files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2T1rQUvyyWcSGVVaHZBZzRtTms/view

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon you run into is called `underfitting`. This happens when the amount our quality of your training data is insufficient, or your network architecture is too small and not capable to learn the problem.

Try normalizing your input data and experiment with different network architectures, learning rates and activation functions.

As @Muhammad Shahzad stated in his comment, adding some Dense Layers after flatting would be a concrete architecture adaption you should try.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, but I tried exactly that and still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can also increase the epoch and must increase the data set. And you also can use-

```
train_datagen= ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip = True,
        channel_shift_range=0.2,
        fill_mode='nearest'
        )
```

for feeding the model more data and I hope you can increase the validation_accuracy.